# Reading in dates from Excel into R

Tags: r, excel, csv, datetime, import

I have multiple `csv` files which I need to read into R. The first column of the files contain dates and times, which I am converting into `POSIXlt` when I have loaded the data frame. Each of my `csv` files have the dates and times formatted in the same way in Excel, however, some files are read in differently.

For example,

My file looks like this once imported:

```
  date                value
1 2011/01/01 00:00:00 39
2 2011/01/01 00:15:00 35
3 2011/01/01 00:30:00 38
4 2011/01/01 00:45:00 39
5 2011/01/01 01:00:00 38
6 2011/01/01 01:15:00 38
```

Therefore, the code I use to amend the format is:

```
DATA$date <- as.POSIXlt(DATA$date,format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
```

However, some files are being read in as:

```
  date             value
1 01/01/2011 00:00 39
2 01/01/2011 00:15 35
3 01/01/2011 00:30 38
4 01/01/2011 00:45 39
5 01/01/2011 01:00 38
6 01/01/2011 01:15 38
```

Which means my format section of my code does not work and gives an error. Therefore, is there anyway to automatically detect which format the `date` column is in? Or, is there a way of knowing how it will be read, since the format of the column in Excel is the same on both.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064292/guess-formats-r-lubridate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the wrong formatting string for your date input, I seem to get `NA` values.  If this be the case, you solve this problem in two steps.  First, format the dates from Excel assuming that you have all three of hours, minutes, and seconds:

```
date.original <- DATA$date
DATA$date <- as.POSIXlt(DATA$date,format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
```

This should leave `NA` values in the `date` column for those dates which be missing seconds.  Then you can try this:

```
DATA$date[is.na(DATA$date)] <- as.POSIXlt(date.original, format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
```

This should cover the remaining data.

**Data**

```
DATA <- data.frame(date=c('2011/01/01 00:00:00', '2011/01/01 00:15',
                          '2011/01/01 00:30:00', '2011/01/01 00:45'),
                   value=c(39, 35, 38, 39))
```