# Guess dates over list of dfs using `anytime`

Tags: r, list, date

Mock data:

```
my_list <- list(structure(list(start = c("2023-09-12T18:59:49.336+01:00", 
                                     "2023-09-18 07:29:34", "z2023-09-18 07:29:34"), country = c("USA", 
                                                                                                 "UK", "UK")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)), 
            structure(list(start = c("2023-09-16T21:12:51.288Z", "2019-11-30", 
                                     "2019-30-11"), country = c("UK", "Canada", "France")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                -3L)))
```

Using the second answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064292/guess-formats-r-lubridate) (please note, the first answer does not work for me), I want to convert all dates to year-month-day.

I do:

```
library(anytime)
lapply(my_list, transform,
       start = anydate(start)
)
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
       start country
1 2023-09-12     USA
2 2023-09-18      UK
3       <NA>      UK

[[2]]
       start country
1 2023-09-16      UK
2 2019-11-30  Canada
3       <NA>  France
```

As one can see, it does not work for two dates, which are coerced to NA. Note, my real data has dozens of dfs and thousands of dates, with no unique format.

How do we do this? Desired output:

```
[[1]]
       start country
1 2023-09-12     USA
2 2023-09-18      UK
3 2023-09-18      UK

[[2]]
       start country
1 2023-09-16      UK
2 2019-11-30  Canada
3 2019-11-30  France
```

**UPDATE**

1. Question was updated following Andre Wildberg's answer
2. I need to return *all* columns contained in the dfs, not just date
3. I ideally wish to use `transform`, and to be able to do any modification on other variables (i.e., not only dates, see example below) if needed
4. Solution does *not* need to use `anytime`, though

(Example to illustrate Update point 3:)

```
lapply(my_list, transform,
       start = anydate(start),
       country = as.factor(country) # etc.
)
```

Further, final format need to be a `Date` and `Factor`, respectively:

```
List of 2
 $ :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ start  : Date[1:3], format: "2023-09-12" "2023-09-18" NA
  ..$ country: Factor w/ 2 levels "UK","USA": 2 1 1
 $ :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ start  : Date[1:3], format: "2023-09-16" "2019-11-30" NA
  ..$ country: Factor w/ 3 levels "Canada","France",..: 3 1 2
```

Comment: How would you decide in cases 2019-12-11, 2019-11-12?

Comment: We couldn't indeed, but Andre's answer makes Ymd a default, which is fine for me in this case.

Comment: Not sure why this question was closed? My example is reproducible, I added precisions, and accepted the answer. I am always happy to improve if I am told how. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An approach with `parse_date_time`. Using `sub` to pull out the date part of the string.

EDIT: with updated data

```
library(lubridate)

lapply(my_list, \(x) 
  setNames(data.frame(
      parse_date_time(
        sub(".*(\\d{4}-\\d+-\\d+).*", "\\1", x[,"start"]), 
        orders=c("Ymd", "Ydm")), 
      x[,-1]), # everything but the first "start" column
    names(x)))
[[1]]
       start country
1 2023-09-12     USA
2 2023-09-18      UK
3 2023-09-18      UK

[[2]]
       start country
1 2023-09-16      UK
2 2019-11-30  Canada
3 2019-11-30  France
```

Keep in mind that ambivalent dates like `2023-08-09` <> `2023-09-08` are interpreted through the first rule `Ymd`

Using `transform`

```
lapply(my_list, \(x) 
  transform(x, 
    start=parse_date_time(sub(".*(\\d{4}-\\d+-\\d+).*", "\\1", start), 
            orders=c("Ymd", "Ydm")), 
    country=as.factor(country)))
```

Comment: Many thanks, that said, on actual data, it returns the error "All formats failed to parse. No formats found." Any hint? Please also see UPDATE to my question.

Comment: See EDIT. The updates are not related to the date-problem though.

Comment: Thanks! That said, I still get the error "All formats failed to parse. No formats found" (related to the date-problem). Also, Country is just an example. I have hundred other vars, and I need a solution that return them all (even if they were not modified or mentioned). Also, how do you transform Country (for example) to factor in your solution? See point 3 and example at the end of question. Thanks so much

Comment: If the code works with the posted data maybe your original data is organized differently? To include any columns use the updated code.

Comment: I added a version using `transform`, see if that works with your data.